# onPress event on headerLeft under navigation.setOptions is not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

onPress event on headerLeft under navigation.options is not working it is still performing default functionality not overriding my onPress functionality for this. When I am clicking on back button it is moving to some random page not the previous page from which I am coming, so that's why I am trying to modify default functionality but it is not picking my onPress function.

> 

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: () => <Text onPress={()=>{console.log('back');}}>Back</Text>,
      headerRight: () => <DetailsHeader isFavorite={detail.FVT_YN === "Y"} onSharePress={() => _onSharePress(detail)} onFavoritePress={() => _onFavoritePress(detail)} />,
    });
  }, [navigation, detail]);
```

In my app there are multiple bottom navigation tabs are there, so if I remove all other tabs and only keep one home tab then it is working fine, but when multiple tabs are there then back button move to any other tab page.
I have tried several ways but none of them working, so please help me find out the solution of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: () => <Pressable onPress={()=>{console.log('back');}}><Text>Back</Text></Pressable>,
      headerRight: () => <DetailsHeader isFavorite={detail.FVT_YN === "Y"} onSharePress={() => _onSharePress(detail)} onFavoritePress={() => _onFavoritePress(detail)} />,
    });
  }, [navigation, detail]);
```

Comment: Not worked for me.